# How to execute "Run Rule Now" in Outlook Online using Exchange Online Powershell?

Tags: powershell, outlook, exchange-server, rules, exchange-online

I've looked over all of the [Exchange Online Powershell commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/?view=exchange-ps#mailboxes) related to mailboxes and rule processing, but I can't seem to locate a command or parameter that allows Powershell to execute the "Run Rule Now" function on demand. Perhaps I'm missing something glaring here, but could someone point me in the direction of where I could find this command to run Outlook Online rules on demand using Powershell? Thanks!